# Annulus from GeoDisks: drawing a ring on a map

Tags: geographics

Good afternoon! I am trying to draw a shaded ring on a map.

The first step I tried was a simple disk. I achieved this with the following:

```
GeoGraphics[GeoDisk[Here, Quantity[10,"Miles"]]]
```

This uses a single [`GeoDisk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoDisk.html). I thought I could use a [`RegionDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference.html) to get an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)) (as I believe it's called). However, this seems to only be for [`Disk`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html#3855366) symbols (not `GeoDisk`).

```
GeoGraphics[
  RegionDifference[
    GeoDisk[Here, Quantity[10.5,"Miles"]],
    GeoDisk[Here, Quantity[11.5,"Miles"]]]]
```

This fails with "...is not a correctly specified region."

Then I thought I might use a [`GeoCircle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoCircle.html), setting the thickness to 1 mile, but it seems you can only specify something like "Thick", not a geographical distance.

I don't have much experience with Wolfram Language, but this is what I've tried so far. I've also found the [GeoGraphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeoGraphics.html) tutorial and the [Maps & Cartography](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MapsAndCartography.html) guide related and useful. So, am I missing something to achieve what I want [a 10-mile radius shaded ring with a thickness of 1 mile]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
p = Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}];
rOut = Quantity[2000, "Miles"];
rIn = Quantity[1000, "Miles"];

GeoGraphics[FilledCurve[{{GeoCircle[p, rOut]}, {GeoCircle[p, rIn]}}], GeoGridLines -> True]
```

[image]
This solution will also be valid with any projection.

Comment: Very nice, I am surprised `FilledCurve` works with GeoGraphics primitives, it is not documented ... and you can even fill it with texture !

Comment: `GeoGraphics` is basically an extension of `Graphics`, and it inherits the `Graphics` capabilities. You can see `GeoGraphics` as `Graphics` on the projected map space, with the added ability of pre-converting anything on the surface of the Earth to the flat map space using the geoprojection.

Comment: `FilledCurve`, perfect! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Jose, here's an off topic report: `GeoGraphics[{AbsolutePointSize@12, Point[{-149., 63.}]}, 
 GeoRange -> Entity["Country", "Mexico"]]`

Comment: Do you mean `GeoGraphics[{AbsolutePointSize@12, Point[GeoPosition[{63., -149.}]]}, GeoRange -> Entity["Country", "Mexico"]]` ? GeoRange determines which part of the Earth is shown. PlotRange determines which part of the map is shown. The default of GeoRange is Automatic. The default of PlotRange is All. Point[{x, y}] is a point on the map, and will be included by default. GeoPosition[{lat, lon}] is a point on the Earth, and will be included if it is included in the GeoRange value.

Comment: @jose thanks, you are right. p.s. sorry for delay, I was not notified without @ kuba.

Answer (score 2):

```
GeoGraphics[{Red, Thickness[.2], 
  GeoCircle[Here, Quantity[10, "Miles"]]}, 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[25, "Kilometers"]]
```

[image]

Then you can find me. :)

Comment: Thank you for your response! What units are used in `Thickness`? I'm looking for a 1 mile thickness. Is the `.2` in kilometers?

Comment: The range is 25km,the 0.2 is 20% of 25km

Comment: You are in 上海！wow,close to me